# Ng-show or ng-if condition if a date equals one of multiple dates in an array

Tags: angularjs

With AngularJS, I'm trying to use `ng-show` or `ng-if` in such a way that if today equals one of multiple dates in an array, it should show a specific div.  Is there any way to do something such as:

```
<div ng-show="dateFlag in datesToTrigger">It worked!</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-if="dateFlag in datesToTrigger">It worked!</div>
```

Comment: Possibly this: `ng-show="datesToTrigger.indexOf(dateFlag) !== -1"`

Comment: use ng-if `ng-if="datesToTrigger.includes(dateFlag)"` because it'll not load other divs in dom.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to write a custom function that will check for your date whether it exists in the array and return boolean value based on the result.

```
$scope.checkExists = function () {
   if(array.includes("yourString")
   {
     return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

and in template

```
<div ng-if="checkExists()">It worked!</div>
```